# Amazon S3: how to set requests to use virtual host in ruby aws sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Currently, I am sending GET requests to S3 using aws-sdk ruby as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#
require 'aws-sdk'
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'test',     endpoint:'http://10.0.23.45:8081')
my_bucket = s3.bucket('test.bucket-name')
my_bucket.objects.limit(50).each do |obj|
   puts "  #{obj.key} => #{obj.etag}"
end
```

But the request is trying to hit this url endpoint(virtual hosting):

```
http://test.bucket-name.10.0.23.45:8081
```

I would like to use path style addressing instead. This is what I want the request url endpoint to look like:

```
http://10.0.23.45:8081/test.bucket-name/
```

Any idea how to set path style addressing instead of virtual hosting address? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for my own question after looking at the source code of ruby aws-sdk [Source Code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/global_configuration.rb)

```
 Aws.config[:s3] = { force_path_style: true }
```

Adding the above line forced to use path style addressing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set option `:virtual_host` to `true` according to [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#public_url-instance_method).

So in your case something like this should work:

```
s3.bucket('10.0.23.45:8081').object('test.bucket-name').public_url(virtual_host: true)
#=> "http://10.0.23.45:8081/test.bucket-name/"
```